# does h.264 have separate audio and video

Tags: video, h.264

We are requesting video producers to send us video and we've worded our request as below. Please tell me if our request makes sense?

"One 720 p editable file in h.264 in an mp4 or AVI container with separate tracks for audio and video."

My question specifically is: does h.264 even have separate tracks for audio and video or am I making a mistake?

P.S.
We know h.264 is really a presentation format, but the small adjustments we make re-render well enough and absolute perfection is not the goal.

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify "separate tracks", just the audio and video specs you accept. All common containers will handle multiple disparate tracks including video, audio, text (captions etc). h.264 is a video codec; you could choose (or allow) any of several audio codecs.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Mack, for your answer.
I just could not nail that little fact down.